# How to avoid different user use the same cache data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, cache-control

I have a server in ASP.NET and a web server in JS.

The API server will add a `cache-control` header for each GET method and set the expire time, so the web will not consume twice within that period for the same resources.

So my issue is: In the web side, when i GET a resource then logout and login to another user, for the same API request, the browser still uses the cached value, which is for the previous user.

Is there any way or attributes to prevent that ?

**[Expected result]**: Different user should not use a same cached value.

Comment: You said "web server in JS". Do you mean the client (presumably browser) is using Javascript? Or something else?

Comment: @John Yes, the client is using JS

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a simple solution, but i am new to the cache so it took me a while.

[Solution]: Found I can use header value `Vary` to control when to use cached value and when not.